# Can't access variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
jQuery(window).on('resize', fuction() {
    var width = jQuery(this).innerWidth();
    console.log(width) // works fine.
});
console.log(width); // undefined
```

Does anyone know how to fix this global variable problem in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `width` variable outside of `resize` handler

```
var width = jQuery(window).on("resize", function() {
              width = jQuery(this).innerWidth();
              console.log("inside resize event", width) // works fine.
        }).innerWidth();
console.log("outside resize event", width);// set to `.innerWidth()` initially
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/I9ueibR00JCDQtxy2p6D?p=preview

Comment: No, that doesn't help beacause I want to measure the innerWidth constantly.

Comment: @phpWarrior `js` at Answer should set `width` variable to return value of current `.innerWidth()`, both initally and at each `resize` event, which should   _"measure the innerWidth constantly"_, see http://plnkr.co/edit/I9ueibR00JCDQtxy2p6D?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic scope issue - in your code, the variable width is only defined on the resize and is not available until then. You would need to run the function on document ready in order to access it. Easiest way is to create a common function that is called first on document ready and then on subsequent resize events.

```
function width(){
    var width = window.innerWidth();
    console.log(width);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  width();
})

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  width();
});
```

Comment: But i want to have access to the var width constantly and mesure the window width all the time. that's the issue here.

Comment: which is why you need to do it on document ready - so that you have the initial width and then you can do something with it or store it in local / session storage for use later. Then on window resize you can run the function again - compare the new value to the store value and dpo something else.

Comment: Ok I'll try that, but i did'nt sleep all night fighting with it, so i will take a  break.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a jQuery problem, thats how javascript works. You declared `width` as `var` which creates the variable in the local scope. If you drop the `var`, you'll not declare a new variable but look for one in the parent scopes until you found one or until you are at global scope, at which point the variable is created at global scope. You can force-access global-scope by using `window.width`

Answer (score 0):

Remove var from width !! It will be treated as global variable and will 100% work !!

Answer (score 0):

Simple adjustments ... declare `var` outside the event handler...and trigger resize after the event handler is declared so it  sets variable value on page load

```
var width;
jQuery(window).on('resize', fuction() {
    width = jQuery(this).innerWidth();        
}).resize();
console.log(width);
```